# Showing value (URL/Thumbnail) from Foreign key in Admin

Tags: django, django-models

I want to show an small preview image in Django Admin. I have made this hack, which works when the key is in the actual model itself.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    prod_name = models.CharField ("Name", max_length=130)
    image = models.URLField(max_length=340, blank=True, null=true)
    def admin_image(self):
        return '<center><a href="%s" target="_blank"><img src="%s"/width="100px"></a></center>' %(self.image, self.image)
    admin_image.allow_tags = True
```

However, I want it to show an image (read a URL) from a Foreign Key. I tried the following but no luck:

```
class Product_Option(models.Model):
    colour = models.CharField (max_length=80, blank=True, null=True)
    size = models.CharField (max_length=80, blank=True, null=True)
    image_default = models.URLField(max_length=340, blank=True, null=True) # SHOW this image by

class Product(models.Model):
    prod_name = models.CharField ("Name", max_length=130)
    image = models.URLField(max_length=340, blank=True, null=true)
    Default_Image = models.ForeignKey(Product_Option, blank=True, null= True)
```

---

### Admin.py

```
class ProductAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = ProductResource
    def admin_image(self, obj):
        return '<center><a href="%s" target="_blank"><img src="%s"/width="100px"></a></center>' %(obj.Stock_Image.image_default.url, obj.Stock_Image.image_default.url)
    admin_image.allow_tags = True
    list_display = ('prod_name','admin_image')
    readonly_fields = ('admin_image',)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a little confusing, and you should be careful about putting HTML type code in your models. That being said, assuming you are trying to add thumbnails to your admin via foreignkey relations, this would be the easiest approach:

```
from django.utils.html import format_html

class ProductAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = ProductResource
    list_display = ('prod_name', 'admin_image')
    readonly_fields = ('admin_image',)

    def admin_image(self, obj):
        return format_html('<center><a href="{0}" target="_blank"><img src="{1}"/width="100px"></a></center>', obj.Default_Image.image_default, obj.Default_Image.image_default)
        admin_image.allow_tags = True
```

Note: Notice the use of `format_html()`. Always use it in these cases to avoid vulnerabilities, as it escapes possibly malicious code.

Also, you were trying to use `image_default.url`, which only exists on an `ImageField`, not a `URLField`. I removed that as well in favor of just `image_default`.